# Implementing a simple shell

Tags: c, string, shell, fork, execvp

Making a simple -type shell, using fork and execvp functions to run the commands from the stdin line.

However, things like `ls` work, but not `ls -all -S`.
It will execute `ls`, but nothing will be printed for `ls -all`

The only idea I can come up with is that there is a "\n" somewhere in the command, but I don't know how to get it out or even where it is....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
//Libs ^^^^ Defs vvvvvvvv
#define comlen 4096                     //Max command length
#define comarg 32             //Max argument length

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  char buff; //command buffer
    char* comand[comlen];
    int i;
  do
  {
        i = 0;
    printf("simsh: ");

        char* whtspc = strtok (fgets(&buff, comlen, stdin)," ");  //get input and tokenize
        printf("[%lu]   ::   %s------------\nEND OF BUFF TEST\n", strlen(&buff), &buff);

    while (whtspc != NULL)
    {
          comand[i]=(char*)malloc((sizeof(char)*strlen(whtspc))); //alloctie mem for commands
          strncpy(comand[i], whtspc, strlen(whtspc)-1);                     //coppy comand token to array index i
          whtspc = strtok (NULL, " ");                                                      //grab next token
            i++;                                                                                                        //incriment
            /*trying to change new line character to NULL so that commands can be passed properly*/
//          if (comand[strlen(comand[i]) - 1] == "\n") 
//          {
//              comand[strlen(comand[i]) - 1] = '\0';
//          }
            //breka out incase index oversteps
            if (i == 4096)
                break;
    }
        //last entry in command should be null
        comand[i] = NULL;
        //fork to run in background
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0)
        {
            //testing and pass comands to execvp
            printf("START OF COMAND TEST\n!!!!!!!!!%s!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n %lu\nEND OF COMAND TEST\n\n",comand[1], strlen(comand[0]));
            execvp(comand[0], &comand);
        }

        else
        {
            //parent wait on child.
            waitpid(pid, &i, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
        }
    }
    while(1);

  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be welcomed.

If it helps at all , here is the terminal output of the code::

```
simsh: ls
[3]   ::   ls
------------
END OF BUFF TEST
START OF COMAND TEST
!!!!!!!!!(null)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 2
END OF COMAND TEST

chop_line.c  chop_line.h  list.c  list.h  Makefile  Makefile~  One  simsh1  simsh1.c  simsh1.c~
simsh: ls -all
[2]   ::   ls------------
END OF BUFF TEST
START OF COMAND TEST
!!!!!!!!!-all!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 1
END OF COMAND TEST

simsh: echo
[5]   ::   echo
------------
END OF BUFF TEST
START OF COMAND TEST
!!!!!!!!!(null)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 4
END OF COMAND TEST


simsh: echo all
[4]   ::   echo------------
END OF BUFF TEST
START OF COMAND TEST
!!!!!!!!!all!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 3
END OF COMAND TEST

simsh: echo echo
[4]   ::   echo------------
END OF BUFF TEST
START OF COMAND TEST
!!!!!!!!!echo!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 3
END OF COMAND TEST
```

Comment: Can you describe more precisely the unexpected behavior ?

Comment: When I do commands such as `ls` it works, but when I try to do something like `ls -all -S` it doesn't execute the command. Or if I do `echo testing` it won't echo "testing". I'm not sure why

Comment: Might want to check out the source code for [dash](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src), it's a small posix shell without extras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `fgets` is reading to a *single* character `buff`. You should read into a buffer of characters. Second, `fgets` keeps the newline at the end of the read string, so you may want to remove it first, e.g.:

```
char buff[4096];
if (!fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin)) {
    // error or EOF
    return 1;
}
int len = strlen(buff);
if (len > 0 && buff[len-1] == '\n') {
    buff[--len] = '\0';
}
char *whtspc = strtok(buff, " ");
```

You must also replace all references to `&buff` with `buff`.

In addition to this, your `malloc` is also wrong, and allocates one character less than is required (`strlen` is without the terminating NUL):

```
if (!(comand[i] = malloc(strlen(whtspc)+1))) {
    return 1; // out of memory
}
(void) strcpy(comand[i], whtspc);
```

Correspondingly your `strncpy` was copying one character less than required. This is what made your original code accidentally work for a single-word input because it had the effect of removing the trailing `'\n'` for you in that case, but in every other case it removed the last character of the word itself.

And the second argument to `execvp` should be just the `comand` (sic) array:

```
execvp(comand[0], comand);
```

Comment: Implementing your suggestion gives a segfault. Even if I take only the part from after you suggest using the `!fgets` if statement, then the `ls` command doesn't work anymore. I'm beginning to think I was wrong about this being the cause of the issues I'm having. 

I consulted the man page for fgets as well, given that the syntax is  ` char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);` is it correct to give `char buff[comlen]` as `char *s`? It also stores in the `\n` as well as appending `\0`. I'm not really sure what the problem is now.

Comment: `buff` in that case decays to a pointer to its first element, i.e., `&(buff[0])`. C strings are NUL-terminated, but `strlen` does not count the terminator so `buff[strlen(buff)-1]` is the last character when `buff` does not contain the empty string (which would have `strlen` of zero).

Comment: @user3078156 I edited the answer to show the complete set of changes required to make it work with both `ls` and `ls -l` input. In addition to these changes you are still leaking memory because you don't free the `malloc`'ed results, etc.

Comment: I could not get your suggestions to work at all... It kept giving me segfaults.  You did explain how execvp works much better than the man page did, so thankyou. I used @Guilherme Salazar's suggestions though and they work... for the most part.

Comment: @user3078156 See my comment to @GuilhermeSalazar's answer for a list of some bugs in his code. As for not getting my suggestions to work, I think you may have left some of your conflicting old code in place; the first code block replaces the `char* whtspc = …` line, the second replaces `comand[i]=(char*)malloc` and the `strncpy` below it, the third replaces `execpvp`, and then you must replace all `&buff` with `buff` and remove your `char buff;`. With the your code copypasted and these changes, it should work.

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong, but it was something big. Just copypastaing yours into the places you dictated seemed to fix it... Thank you very much. I will never know what I did wrong. Thank you!

Comment: are you kidding me? `char buff[4096];` ... its more complex than that -1. Several technique can be applied to handle this memory issue, solutions go from `buffer gap`, `linked line` to the `paged buffer gap` and many others techniques, in the worse scenario `readline()` could be used instead, but definitely not a fixed buffer of 4096 bytes, it's too little and too much at the same time.

Comment: @Kira Umm, this seems like a homework assignment, I very much doubt that `readline` is appropriate. In any case the `4096` came from the OP's question. And even many real shells have low enough a maximum command-line length that it could be a constant-size buffer on modern “desktop” systems, e.g., 262144 is common.

Comment: @Kira Also, the question was basically how to get command-line arguments working, not how to implement a dynamic input buffer for a real shell, and I think my answer is overly complicated as is. Seems like an inappropriate and malicious downvote.

Comment: @Arkku touche, reading carefully from top to bottom, yes, it feels like a malicious dowvote. My apologizes.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `fgets` should be a pointer to a buffer where the string is copied into. You are passing a pointer to a single `char`.

Second, `execvp` expects two arguments: a filename and a null-terminated list of command-line arguments which, by convention, starts with the filename itself.

I took the liberty to make some modifications to your code, both fixing the issues I pointed above and making it a little more readable.

Note that there's a memory leak in the code below (fix it :). There might be other issues that I didn't notice.

I implemented a shell a while ago; if you want to take a look, my GitHub URL is in my profile (BEWARE: ugly college homework code).

Hope it helps!

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                      
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                     
#include <string.h>                                                                                     
#include <unistd.h>                                                                                     
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>                                                                                  
#include <sys/wait.h>                                                                                   

#define COMLEN 4096                                                                                     
#define COMARG_N 32                                                                                     
#define TRUE 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{                                                                                                       
    char *token;                                                                                        
    char *args[COMARG_N];                                                                               
    char *buff;                                                                                         
    int i;                                                                                              
    pid_t pid;                                                                                          

    while(TRUE) {                                                                                       
        printf("simsh: ");                                                                            

        buff = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * COMLEN);                                                 
        fgets(buff, COMLEN, stdin);                                                                   

        if (buff[strlen(buff) - 1] == '\n')                                                           
            buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0';                                                            

        i = 0;                                                                                        
        token = strtok (buff, " ");                                                                   

        while (token != NULL && i < COMARG_N - 1) {                                                   
            args[i] = token;                                                                          
            token = strtok (NULL, " ");                                                               
            i++;                                                                                      
        }                                                                                             

        args[i] = NULL;                                                                               

        pid = fork();                                                                                 
        if (pid == 0)                                                                                 
            execvp(args[0], &args[0]);                                                                
        else                                                                                          
            waitpid(pid, &i, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);                                                 

        free(buff);                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                 

    return 0;                                                                                             
}
```

Comment: Why would you `malloc` and `free` a new `buff` for every iteration of the loop? Also, you are calling `strlen(buff)` twice in a row, and do not check the return value of `fgets` before `strlen(buff)`, or the length before indexing `buff[strlen(buff) - 1]`. As stylistic hints, `sizeof(char)` is always 1 (i.e. `1 *` is a NOP), `&args[0]` is the same as `args`, you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc`, and defining your own `TRUE` is quite ugly (especially since the C convention is that any non-zero value is “true” - at the very least you should use `stdbool.h` for the standard values).